# Python converting from string to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

From a third party service I'm receiving a date string formatted as follows: `10/08/22, 17:23`.
I want to convert the string into a `datetime` object in order to calculate difference in terms of hours, but I can't get where I'm wrong while trying the following.

```
date_string = 10/08/22, 17:23
date_string = date_string.replace("/", "-").replace(",", "")
time = datetime.strptime(date_string+":00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I tried to use different formats (modifying accordingly the string), like `%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M`, `%Y/%m/%d %H:%M`, `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M` but without success.
I receive an error like this: `ValueError: time data '10-08-22 17:23:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`.
If it is possible to convert the string to date without modifying it I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `%Y` is 4-digit year, why don't you use the format code for 2-digit year instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to change/replace characters in the input string as you can incorporate them into the format string

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = '10/08/22, 17:23'

print(datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d/%m/%y, %H:%M'))
```

**Output:**

```
2022-08-10 17:23:00
```

**Note:**

The format string assumes you're not American

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the question here is bit confusing for me. However, the format that you are specifying in the strptime is different than in the date_string.

However I assume that you want to convert the format into `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M`.
For that first convert it into datetime object of same format as datestring. and change the format.

The below code should work -

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = '10/08/22, 17:23'

# convert to datetime object
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%y, %H:%M')

# datetime object to desired format
formatted_datetime = datetime_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(formatted_datetime)  # Output: 2022-10-08 17:23:00
```

Hope this is helpful.